# How to use allow_nets extra field in dovecot using GSSAPI authentication?

Tags: dovecot, gssapi

I would like to use dovecot withs GSSAPI autentication using userdb with ldap backend. Is there any way on how to use passdb `allow_nets` extra attribute which is stored in ldap database?

Dovecot documentation says:

> GSSAPI requires at least one passdb configured. Note that
> authentication will normally succeed, even if user is not found in any
> passdb. Please configure a userdb if you do not want this.

How to restrict the access from specific networks for some users? `allow_nets` is extra attribute in passdb, not in userdb.